# Why does this prepared statement throw an error?

Tags: php, mysql

Having learnt the basics of PHP and MySQL, I am now learning how to protect against SQL injection attacks by using prepared statements. I have the following code:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $delegateno ;$i++){

        $q = "INSERT INTO delegates (delegate_id,booker_name, booker_email, booker_tel, booker_company, delegate_name, delegate_email, delegate_tel) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )";//Insert delegate information into delegate tables
        $stmt = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'sssssss', $fullname, $email, $tel, $company,$delegatename[$i],$delegateemail[$i],$delegatetel[$i]);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
```

However, this throws:

```
Notice: Query: INSERT INTO delegates (delegate_id,booker_name, booker_email, booker_tel, booker_company, delegate_name, delegate_email, delegate_tel) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )
MySQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why do you set delegate_id if its null anyway ? and after $stmt you have to use $stmt->bind_param() don't you ? im using [THE PDO Class](http://php.net/manual/de/book.pdo.php) to manage my mysql

Comment: I think I added it in just in case back when I was still getting to grips with queries. You'd use ->bind_param() if you were using object oriented style or PDO, but mysqli does it as above, I believe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you're executing the raw query containing the placeholders. You need to [`prepare()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) the query first.

This is how it goes (usually): `prepare` -> `bind_param` -> `execute` -> `fetch`.

Change:

```
$stmt = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
```

to:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $q);
```